# Checking time in every minute in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm making an application that will notify the user every 1, 5 or 30 minute or even every hour.
For example the user opens the program in 5:06 and the program will notify the user in 6:06.

So my current code is notifying the user every 5 minutes using Thread.Sleep() function, but I find it kinda lame.

This is my code:

```
public void timeIdentifier()
    {
        seiyu.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female);
        while(true)
        {
            string alarm = String.Format("Time check");
            seiyu.Speak(alarm);
            string sayTime = String.Format(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt"));
            seiyu.Speak(sayTime);
            // It will sleep for 5 minutes LOL
            Thread.Sleep(300000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: why dont you use Task Schedular for that.Just  a suggestion

Comment: Look at my answer here (is an implementation of a RecurrentCancellableTask), it may solve your problem easily: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472013/how-to-create-a-thread-task-with-a-continuous-loop/35308832#35308832

Comment: I suggest using `Timer`

Comment: @Vicky: how do you configure the task scheduler to notify someone if a program was opened for at least one minute?

Comment: @TimSchmelter-Sir,i was of the opinion that advance setting panel under  Triggers tab gives us option to configure windows schedular to any minute of our choice.

Comment: the application i am making will go to the task tray if minimized..Notification Tray I suppose?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Timers instead of `Thread.Sleep()`:

```
public class Program
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public static void Main()
    {
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000); // interval in milliseconds (here - 5 seconds)

        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ElapsedHandler); // handler - what to do when 5 seconds elaps

        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        // If the timer is declared in a long-running method, use
        // KeepAlive to prevent garbage collection from occurring
        // before the method ends.
        //GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);
    }

    //handler
    private static void ElapsedHandler(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        string alarm = String.Format("Time check");
        seiyu.Speak(alarm);
        string sayTime = String.Format(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt"));
        seiyu.Speak(sayTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: are there any more ways to do it? like looping and incrementing values and stuff?

Answer (score 0):

If you like newer [.NET TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx) syntax yo can write it like this:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Repeat(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Repeat(TimeSpan period)
    {
        Task.Delay(period)
            .ContinueWith(
                t =>
                {
                    //Do your staff here
                    Console.WriteLine($"Time:{DateTime.Now}");
                    Repeat(period);
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Timer object (System.Threading).
The timer object has interval not a timeout.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int firstCallTimeOut = 0;
        int callInterval = 300000;
        object functionParam = new object();//optional can be null
        Timer timer = new Timer(foo,null,firstCallTimeOut,callInterval);
       
    }
    static void foo(object state)
    {
       //TODO
    }
```

Comment: The garbage collector will eventually remove the reference to a local object. So in general case the timer have to do a class field.