# Managing Recurring Tasks

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task

i have a Recurring Cancellable Task launcher taken from this question:

[How to create a thread/Task with a continuous loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472013/how-to-create-a-thread-task-with-a-continuous-loop/35308832#35308832)

```
public static class TaskHelper
{
    public static class RecurrentCancellableTask
    {
        public static Task StartNew(
            Action action,
            TimeSpan pollInterval,
            CancellationToken token,
            TaskScheduler scheduler = null,
            TaskCreationOptions taskCreationOptions = TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
            )
        {
            if (scheduler == null) scheduler = TaskScheduler.Default;
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () =>
                {
                    while (true)
                        try
                        {
                            action();
                            if (token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(pollInterval)) break;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                }, token, taskCreationOptions, scheduler);
        }
    }
}
```

everything works like a charm.
however now i need to put this task launcher inside a loop and launch x job:

```
 foreach (var job in collection)
                    {
                        TaskHelper.RecurrentCancellableTask.StartNew(() => { somecode(job); }, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(i), token);
                    }
```

the collection loop is started every n seconds
if a job from collection has been removed, the job must be stopped.

if a job from collection has been added, the job must run every i milliseconds.

if a job from collection is alredy running every i milliseconds must be ignored and cannot be started another one.

jobs can be launched parallely.

how i can manage this situation? 
is there any task manager pattern where i can look?

Thanks!

D

Comment: Hace a look at hangfire, it s a framework for task

Comment: Copy `collection` to `HashSet`. On other iteration do intersect. Run only new jobs.