# How can I make this a never ending loop with time out every 1 successful process

Tags: c#

This is my code which parses a string coming from a database. The database has around 50 data strings and continuously grows every 5 seconds.

I want this code to enter a never ending loop so if new data arrives and the table is empty it will immediately parse it.

I'm only asking for possible suggestion on how to make this code a never ending looping processor.

Code below

```
private void btnActiveStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connetionString = null;
    SqlConnection cnn;
    connetionString = "Data Source=SAMPLE12345;Initial Catalog=SAMPLE_TABLE;User ID=sa;Password=str0ngp@ssw0rd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
    cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
    cnn.Open();
    string sqlquery = "SELECT top 1 SMSMSG,SMSDT FROM GPRSIN WHERE isHEX = '0'";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, cnn);

    SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        string input = sdr["SMSMSG"].ToString();
        string smsdt = sdr["SMSDT"].ToString();
        int s = input.Length;
        if (s == 105)
        {
            string account       = input.Substring(0, 15);
            txtbxImeiActive.Text = account;                       //ACCOUNT
            DateTime now         = DateTime.Now;              
            String finnow        = now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
            txtbxDateTimeStampFast.Text = finnow.ToString();      //DATETIME
            //Convert date START
            string datetime      = input.Substring(65, 12);
            string hour          = datetime.Substring(0, 2);
            string minutes       = datetime.Substring(2, 2);
            string seconds       = datetime.Substring(4, 2);
            string day           = datetime.Substring(6, 2);
            string month         = datetime.Substring(8, 2);
            string year          = datetime.Substring(10, 2);
            string strdate       = "20" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " ";
            string strtime       = hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ".000";
            string findatetime   = strdate + strtime;
            DateTime gpsdatefast = Convert.ToDateTime(strdate);
            String fingpsdatefast= gpsdatefast.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
            DateTime gpstimesfast = Convert.ToDateTime(strtime);
            String fingpstimefast = gpstimesfast.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
            //Convert date END
            txtbxGpsDateFast.Text = fingpsdatefast.ToString();    //GPSDATE
            txtbxGpsTimeFast.Text = fingpstimefast.ToString();    //GPSTIME
            DateTime trxdatefast  = Convert.ToDateTime(smsdt);
            String fintrxdatefast = trxdatefast.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000");
            txtbxTrxDateFast.Text = fintrxdatefast;

            DateTime trxtimefast  = Convert.ToDateTime(smsdt);
            String fintrxtimefast = trxtimefast.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
            txtbxTrxTimeFast.Text = fintrxtimefast;

            DateTime philtime     = Convert.ToDateTime(findatetime).AddHours(8);
            String finphiltime    = philtime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
            txtbxPhilTimeFast.Text= finphiltime;

            //Convert DMS format to decimal (Degrees and fragment minutes) START LONG
            string deglong        = input.Substring(35, 10);
            string degreeslong    = deglong.Substring(0, 3);
            decimal degfin2       = decimal.Parse(degreeslong);
            string minuteslong    = deglong.Substring(3, 6);
            decimal minfin2       = decimal.Parse(minuteslong);
            decimal resminlong    = minfin2 / 60;
            decimal longresult    = degfin2 + resminlong;

            string gettlong = longresult.ToString();
            string longresultcut = gettlong.Substring(0, 7);
            decimal tlongcut = decimal.Parse(longresultcut);
            //Convert DMS format to decimal (Degrees and fragment minutes) START LONG
            txtbxLongFast.Text    = Math.Round(longresult, 6).ToString();
            txtbxTlong.Text = tlongcut.ToString();

            //Convert DMS format to decimal (Degrees and fragment minutes) START LAT
            string deglat         = input.Substring(25, 9);
            string degreeslat     = deglat.Substring(0, 2);
            decimal degfin1       = decimal.Parse(degreeslat);
            string minuteslat     = deglat.Substring(2, 6);
            decimal minfin1       = decimal.Parse(minuteslat);
            decimal resminlat     = minfin1 / 60;
            decimal latresult     = degfin1 + resminlat;
            string gettlat        = latresult.ToString();
            string latresultcut = gettlat.Substring(0, 6);
            decimal tlatcut      = decimal.Parse(latresultcut);
            //Convert DMS format to decimal (Degrees and fragment minutes) END  LAT
            txtbxLatFast.Text     = Math.Round(latresult, 6).ToString();
            txtbxTlat.Text = tlatcut.ToString();


            string tlocquery = "SELECT LAC,CID,LONG,LAT,STREET,MUNICIPAL FROM TRIANGULATION WHERE lat LIKE " + "'%" + tlatcut.ToString() + "%' AND long LIKE '%" + tlongcut.ToString() + "%'";
            //MessageBox.Show(platequery);
            SqlCommand commandtloc = new SqlCommand(tlocquery, cnn);
            SqlDataReader sdrtloc = commandtloc.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdrtloc.Read())
            {
                string Tlong = sdrtloc["LONG"].ToString();
                txtbxTlong.Text = Tlong.ToString();
                string Tlat = sdrtloc["LAT"].ToString();
                txtbxTlat.Text = Tlat.ToString();

                string Lac = sdrtloc["LAC"].ToString();
                txtbxLac.Text = Lac.ToString();
                string Cid = sdrtloc["CID"].ToString();
                txtbxCid.Text = Cid.ToString();

                string Street = sdrtloc["STREET"].ToString();
                string Municipal = sdrtloc["MUNICIPAL"].ToString();
                txtbxTloc.Text = Street.ToString() + "," + Municipal.ToString();
            }
            string speed = input.Substring(46, 5);
            txtbxSpeedFast.Text = speed;
            string platequery = "SELECT plateno FROM ACCOUNT WHERE senderno =" + "'" + account + "'";
            //MessageBox.Show(platequery);
            SqlCommand commandplate = new SqlCommand(platequery, cnn);
            SqlDataReader sdrplate = commandplate.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdrplate.Read())
            {
                string plate = sdrplate["plateno"].ToString();
                txtbxActivePlate.Text = plate.ToString();
            }

            string locquery = "SELECT NAME,MUNICIPALI FROM ROAD WHERE lat LIKE " + "'%" + tlatcut.ToString() + "%' AND long LIKE '%" + tlongcut.ToString() + "%'";
            //MessageBox.Show(platequery);
            SqlCommand commandloc = new SqlCommand(locquery, cnn);
            SqlDataReader sdrloc = commandloc.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdrloc.Read())
            {
                string name = sdrloc["NAME"].ToString();
                string municipali = sdrloc["MUNICIPALI"].ToString();
                txtbxLocation.Text = name.ToString() + "," + municipali.ToString();
            }
            string engine = input.Substring(21, 1);
            if (engine == "6" || engine == "2")
            {
                txtbxEngineFast.Text = "ON";
            }
            else if (engine == "4" || engine == "0")
            {
                txtbxEngineFast.Text = "OFF";
            }
            if (speed == "000.0")
            {
                txtbxRemarks.Text = "Stopped";
            }
            else
            {
                txtbxRemarks.Text = "Running";
            }
            string alert1 = input.Substring(20, 1);
            txtbxEvents.Text = alert1;
            string odometer = input.Substring(91, 6);
            //Convert hex to decimal and compute Odometer START
            int kmrun = Convert.ToInt32(odometer, 16);
            double kmfin = kmrun / 1000 * 1.852;
            //Convert hex to decimal and compute Odometer END

            txtbxOdometerActive.Text = kmfin.ToString();
            if (alert1 == "2")
            {
                txtbxAlertActive.Text = "CIRCUIT CUT-OFF";
            }
            else if (alert1 == "4")
            {
                txtbxAlertActive.Text = "Over the speed limit";
            }
            else if (alert1 == "6")
            {
                txtbxAlertActive.Text = "Over the speed limit and Circuit Cut-off";
            }
            else if (alert1 == "0")
            {

                if (engine == "1")
                {
                    txtbxAlertActive.Text = "Panic Button";
                }
                else if (engine == "3" || engine == "7")
                {
                    txtbxAlertActive.Text = "Panic Button";
                    txtbxEngineFast.Text = "ON";
                }
                else if (engine == "5")
                {
                    txtbxAlertActive.Text = "Panic Button";
                    txtbxEngineFast.Text = "OFF";
                }
                else if (engine == "8" || engine == "C")
                {
                    txtbxAlertActive.Text = "Seatbelt ON";
                }
                else if (engine == "9" || engine == "D")
                {
                    txtbxAlertActive.Text = "Panic Button and Seatbelt ON";
                }
                else if (engine == "A" || engine == "E")
                {
                    txtbxAlertActive.Text = "Seatbelt ON";
                    txtbxEngineFast.Text = "ON";
                }
                else if (engine == "B" || engine == "F")
                {
                    txtbxAlertActive.Text = "Seatbelt ON and Panic Button";
                    txtbxEngineFast.Text = "ON";
                }
            }
            string status = input.Substring(24, 1);
            if (status == "A")
            {
                txtbxDevStatus.Text = "OK";
            }
            else
            {
                txtbxDevStatus.Text = "Message Not Valid";
            }
            string determinator = input.Substring(16, 3);
            if (determinator == "RA1")
            {
                txtbxDevType.Text = "R10-V2";
            }
            txtbxLastValidDateTime.Text = finnow.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NOT 105"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes Sir. It needs to run everyday

Comment: never ending loops  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402146/cpu-friendly-infinite-loop

Answer (score 2):

you can use `while(true)` loop or `for( ; ; )` for never ending loop

Comment: Sorry for being new to this but where exactly shall i put these.

Comment: add code which you want continuously looping in the while or for loop